# Graphics in devc++

Tags: c++, conio, bgi

After reading many previous answers on the same topic, I was finally able to run a graphic code on my machine. If I give constant values to axis and radius, circle is drawn but not a complete circle.

Please let me know what is wrong with this code.
Code is written in dev 5.11 with 32 bit GCC.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

using namespace std;

main()
{

    int x_axis, y_axis, x, radius, r, d;
    // request auto detection
    int graphdriver = DETECT, graphmode, errorcode;
    //initialize graphics mode
    initgraph(&graphdriver, &graphmode, "");
    cout << "Enter circle x axis: ";
    cin >> x_axis;
    cout << "Enter circle y axis: ";
    cin >> y_axis;
    cout << "Enter circle radius: ";
    cin >> radius;
    r=radius;
    d=1-r;

    while (x<radius)
    {
        if (d<0)
        {
            d=d+2*x+3;
        }
        else
        {
            d=d+2*(x-radius)+5;
            delay(200);
            radius=radius-1;
        }
        x=x+1;
        putpixel(x+x_axis,radius+y_axis,1);
        putpixel(radius+x_axis,x+y_axis,2);
        putpixel(-radius+x_axis,x+y_axis,3);
        putpixel(-x+x_axis,radius+y_axis,4);
        putpixel(-x+x_axis,-radius+y_axis,5);
        putpixel(-radius+x_axis,-x+y_axis,6);
        putpixel(radius+x_axis,-x+y_axis,7);
        putpixel(x+x_axis,-radius+y_axis,8);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: you did not initialize "x", so it could be any random value.